# MySQL Can't create Table i don't know why

Tags: mysql

I always get this error when i try to create a Table:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
```

Executing:
CREATE TABLE `wolveserver`.`new_table` (
);

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`new_table` (
)' at line 1
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `wolveserver`.`new_table` (
)

I gotta say i'm a total Noob, but i wanna fix this.

Comment: Columns are not optional.

Comment: You have to pass minimum one of column, try something like this: `CREATE TABLE aa.new_table (column1 int)`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define your column inside the parenthesis:

```
CREATE TABLE wolveserver.new_table 
 (col1 int,
  col2 varchar(50) 
 );
```

This is rather a basic question, so you should try to google this before asking a question here in SO. To learn more about `CREATE TABLE` syntax for MySQL, visit [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create_table.asp)

Comment: Thanks!
 
As i said, i'm a total newbie to MySQL and i just didn't found anything on Google. Sorry that i asked such an basic question.

Comment: @Wolve A general tip. If you know some of the syntax (like CREATE TABLE), if you enter that and MySQL into google, the first result at "dev.mysql.com/doc" usually has fairly thorough documentation.

Comment: No worries! We all have to start somewhere. :)